# Symfony2 OneToMany relationship - remove action isn't called

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I'm using Symfony 2.4.6 and I'm trying to use OneToMany relationship to manage images added to a banner.

I did read a lot about the deletion of a child element (setting orphanRemoval, adding 'remove' to cascade) but none of those worked for me. What I've noticed is that remove actions isn't called at all on update.
I have 2 classes, Banner and BannerFile and using collection field type for adding images and it seems to work OK except the delete action.

```
class Banner  
{  
    /.../  

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BannerFile", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="banner", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $bannerFiles;  


    /.../  

    /**
     * Remove bannerFiles
     *
     * @param BannerFile $bannerFiles
     */
    public function removeBannerFile(BannerFile $bannerFiles)
    {
        $this->bannerFiles->removeElement($bannerFiles);
    }
}  

class BannerFile
{
    /.../  

    /**
     * @var integer $banner
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", inversedBy="bannerFiles", targetEntity="Banner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $banner; 


    /.../  
}
```

My problem is that the removeBannerFile isn't called.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you run `doctrine:schema:update`? What type of engine you have on the table?

Comment: Table engine is InnoDB. I have run doctrine:schema:update and there isn't anything to update.

Comment: And have you checked the database table's foreign keys if they are indeed there?

Comment: This issue might be useful to you: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/1227

Comment: Have you tried setting the collection fields option `by reference` to `false`? I had an issue where the associated item wouldn't delete without this being set. I'm sure there are reasons but I can't remember them.

Comment: I've figured out what was the problem but it's embarrassing now. The problem was that I don't actually delete anything from the table but add a timestamp and I've a filter for queries which will add soft delete condition. The problem I had was that my local MySQL server time is few hours ahead so even the entries were deleted it wouldn't take that into account because the time was ahead the current time. I didn't realize that until today when I turn on my machine and could see all the files deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you use a database table engine type that does not support foreign keys (such as `MyISAM`).

Change your engine type to `InnoDB`, then run the following code to update your database schema.

```
php console doctrine:schema:update
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `cascade` to the `ManyToOne` definition:

```
class BannerFile
{
    /.../  

    /**
     * @var integer $banner
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", inversedBy="bannerFiles", targetEntity="Banner", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $banner; 


     /.../  
}
```